# Why does this SQL search give this incompatibility error?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlexception

I'm having this error in my project when attempting to search using SQL for a specific name. When I type the name into a textbox and search.

This is the code used:

```
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * From MovTable where NameOfMov = '" & NameSearchTB.Text & "'", sqlcon)
    da.Fill(MovieSearchdt)
```

MovTable is the SQLDataTable
NameOfMov is the column I'm searching in.

This is the error appearing after attempting to search:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.'**

Comment: I suggest you find a well-designed database to use for your practice until you have sufficient experience to design your own. Try MS sample database [World Wide Importers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/wide-world-importers-what-is?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

The message is rather obvious. It has to with the table structure. The column `NameOfMov` seems to be `ntext` (Unicode text).

The name of a movie should fit in a `varchar` or `nvarchar` column so I doubt that `ntext` is a good choice here.

Some strategies are described here: 
[SQL SERVER – Fix: Error : 402 The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-fix-error-402-the-data-types-ntext-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator/)

Note that text/ntext are being **deprecated**:

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Source: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Another point repeated endlessly: always use **parameterized queries**. This code is unsafe (SQL injections) and will choke on characters like the single quote. This is not the way to do it in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot fix the datatype of field in your database as suggested by Anonymous in his answer then using parameters might work.

**You should always use parameters** to avoid Sql injection.

```
Private Function GetMovieData(NameToSearch As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("select * From MovTable where NameOfMov = @Name;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NText).Value = NameToSearch
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetMovieData(NameSearchTB.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

This separates the User Interface code from the Data Access code. The button knows nothing about where the data is coming from and the GetMovieDate is not concerned with how or where the data is used.